# How to create new method at runtime c#?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I am creator dynamic reporting system that accept calls from javascript within browsers.

I have the following report class,

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Report
    {
        public Report(IEnumerable<Action<object>> actions)
        {
            foreach (var action in actions)
            {
                //here i want to create new methods that are public and have method name as the action method name
            }

        }
    }
```

and in the caller class i have

```
    public class caller{
          private void MyMethod(object obj){ //do something}

          report = new report(MyMethod);
    }
```

What i need to do, is after calling the constructor the report class should generate new method (which is COM visible) and give it the name as MyMethod, and inside it it should invoke the orginal MyMethod

```
    public static MyMethod(object obj)
    {
    // in here it should invoke the actions[0].invoke(obj) 
    }
```

Comment: You have the [CodeDomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate code. What you currently ask is vague and very broad. Try to narrow down please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create a dictionary of each action and its name and then lookup the item in the dictionary by its name. then call the action.

```
    Dictionary<string, Action<object>> _methodDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>();
    public void Report(IEnumerable<Action<object>> actions)
    {
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            // you need to get your name somehow.
            _methodDictionary.Add(action.GetType().FullName, action);
        }
    }
    public void callMethod(string actionName, object itemToPass)
    {
        if(_methodDictionary.ContainsKey(actionName))
            _methodDictionary[actionName].Invoke(itemToPass);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this wont make the method accessible through COM, i need to call it from Javascript like this [function(){return window.external.MyMethod(this.id);}]

Comment: Why not? you would do this in my example. [function(){return window.external.callMethod("MyMethod", this.id);}]